# Display Live Time for Specific Time Zone using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Could anyone please assist me on the below.

I have the JavaScript code to display live time and it takes the system current time, but i want to display the time for specific time zone which is (Asia/Dhaka). How can i do that with this code?

```
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}

function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  // add a zero in front of numbers<10
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    startTime()
  }, 500);
}
startTime();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}

function startTime() {
  var asiaDhaka = new Date().toLocaleString([], { timeZone: "Asia/Dhaka" });
  var today = new Date(asiaDhaka);

  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  // add a zero in front of numbers<10
  var isFormat12H = true;
  var ampm = "";
  if (isFormat12H) {
    ampm = h >= 12 ? "pm" : "am";
    h = h % 12;
    h = h ? h : 12;
  }
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + ampm;
  t = setTimeout(function () {
    startTime();
  }, 1000);
}
startTime();
```

Comment: Instead of setting to `"en-US"` you can set to "nothing" by using `[]`.

Comment: Thankssss. This works perfectly, but one more thing i want, how i will manage the time format from 24 hrs to 12 hrs format in this code?

Comment: I edited my code. If answer helped you please check my answer correct :)

Comment: @iAmOren thanks a lot, this is what i was looking for. Really appreciate, thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [Intl.DateTimeFormat Api](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/#sec-12.1)

```js
let options = {
    timeZone: 'Asia/Dhaka',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'numeric',
    day: 'numeric',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric',
  },
  myDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], options);

setInterval(() => {
  console.log(myDate.format(new Date()));
}, 1000);
```

You may need to check for [browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=Intl)

Comment: this code is not giving me the live running time. i have to refresh every time to see how much the seconds goes. could you please suggest me another code which works like real time

Comment: @AhmedMohammed, if you want 24hr format, add `hour12: false` to `options`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```java
let time = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "Asia/Dhaka" });
```

Comment: Instead of setting to `"en-US"` you can set to "nothing" by using `[]`.